# SQL : split a single row into multiple rows using capacity

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a few items order by on the delivery date, I have the following items.

```
Item    Qty    Delivery date,
C       400    02/03/2021
B       200    02/14/2021
A       350    02/16/2021
D       300    02/19/2021
```

I can only do about `150` items a day (`Capacity`). My plan start date is 01/20/2021 ,Sunday is not plan and cannot exceed the Delivery date, I’ll need result like this:

```
Item    Qty    Delivery date    Plan Date
C       150    02/03/2021       01/20/2021
C       150    02/03/2021       01/21/2021
C       100    02/03/2021       01/22/2021
B       50     02/14/2021       01/22/2021
B       150    02/14/2021       01/23/2021
A       150    02/16/2021       01/25/2021
A       150    02/16/2021       01/26/2021
A       50     02/16/2021       01/27/2021
D       100    02/19/2021       01/27/2021
D       150    02/19/2021       01/28/2021
D       50     02/19/2021       01/29/2021
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What did you try and what is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you try using cursor for this case.

Comment: this is not an answer. Should be under comments